# How do I stop windows update writing to drives other than C:\?

Tags: permissions, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Installer using usb drive for temp purposes](https://superuser.com/questions/71325/windows-installer-using-usb-drive-for-temp-purposes)

Windows Update seems to download updates to the drive with the most freespace. This is incredibly inconvenient and inconsiderate behaviour. How do you force it to stick to a single drive?

Would removing NTFS "SYSTEM" rights be sufficient? This would break search, so it's not ideal.

Comment: I was unaware of this.. what gives you the impression it's downloading to the drive with the most space? I'm gonna have to watch my data drive next big update I do..

Comment: @Bob I saw a comment to that effect. I know that it's writing to drives other than C or even drives with pagefile. It could perhaps be the drive with the highest percentage freespace.

Comment: Have you notice that which update is installing on other drive rather than C:/?

Comment: Its not inconsiderate, its a Windows "feature" ;-)