# Windows 7 update temp cache

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, hard-drive-cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Installer using usb drive for temp purposes](https://superuser.com/questions/71325/windows-installer-using-usb-drive-for-temp-purposes)

Recently I re-installed windows 7 to a 64GB SSD. However, I'm noticing a strange behavior.
Windows updates are taking forever. I noticed that the temp cache is being dumped to my external slow usb G: drive. Where I see directories like: a73187a30a698b471f2e142a322a41fc being created for every windows update.

Why is windows using G: and not C:? is there a registry setting that I can change? If I disconnect G: I get G: not found errors even for regular msi files.

Answer (score 1):

Check you environment variables. They usually have an entry for %TMP% and %temp%.

[image: Screenshot of system panel with Advanced system setting circled]
[image: Screenshot of Environment variable screen]